# How to create global constant of a class - C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants

I'm trying to create a class of complex number and want to create the imaginary unit *i* as constant. I want to be able to use it in any code when the class is included. For example :

```
#include "complex.h"
complex c = 2*i;
```

I've tried to define it that way : `static const complex i` in complex.h under `public:` and `const complex complex::i = complex(0,1)` in complex.cpp. But when I write the code on the top in main.cpp , I get undeclared variable error.

How can I do this?

**Note** : I've defined the `=` and `*` operators

Comment: How about declaring `i` as `public` static const data member?

Comment: Of course it's undefined -- you made it private.

Comment: @CareyGregory Whether it is private or not doesn't affect whether it is defined or not.  In fact, access has no impact what so ever on name lookup.  All it means is that if the compiler finds a private name with the look up (or overload resolution resolves to a private function), you get an error.

Comment: @JamesKanze I understand that.  My point was simply that making it private caused the compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `complex::i` but you are trying to use `i`. Either change your code to

```
complex c = 2 * complex::i;
```

Or create a global constant `i` (note: that’s not a good idea; but you might do it inside a namspace).

Comment: Ok, then how can create a global constant or do it inside a namespace?

Comment: @user2145816 Simply `complex const i = complex::i;` on namespace scope within the header will work.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `extern const complex i` in *complex.h*.

If you do not declare `i` to be `extern` it must be defined in every compilation unit that uses it. Linking two such compilation units will then produce a duplicate definition error.

Comment: I don't really recommend having a global object called `i`.

Comment: Neither do I. Unfortunately, the OP did not ask about the pros and cons of global objects, but about how to create them.

Comment: @Oswald Actually, in his question, he asked about a _member_ variable named `i`, not a global.

Comment: The title of the question says, he asked about a *global* variable named `i`. However, reading the question again, I see why some people might come to the conclusion that the question is about a  *member* variable named `i`.